# Notice: Undefined variable: conexao

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Recentemente eu troquei todo o meu código `mysql` pra `mysqli`. Só que isso me gerou muita dor de cabeça.
Ele me dá os seguintes erros:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\header.php on line 44
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\header.php on line 44
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\header.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\Cadastro.class.php on line 15
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\Cadastro.class.php on line 15
```

Não deu pra inserir na hora de inserir.

Atualmente meus códigos estão em:

index.php
cadastro.php
[css/header.php](https://hastebin.com/uhexoqazud.xml) <- está linkado
css/DB.class.php
[css/Cadastro.class.php](https://hastebin.com/fikakiyeca.xml) <- está linkado

> DB.class.php:

```
<?php
class DB{
    public function conectar(){
        $conexao=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","painel")or die("Não foi possível conectar na database.");
    return $conexao;
    }
}
?>
```

Onde foi que eu errei?
Obrigado Fernando, o erros diminuíram. Agora está dando os seguintes erros:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conectar in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\Cadastro.class.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\Programas\wamp64\www\admin\css\Cadastro.class.php on line 15
```

Eu alterei de `$conexao` para `$conectar` nos arquivos `header.php` e `Cadastro.class.php`. 2 erros saíram, só ficaram mais 2.

Comment: Aonde e como está chamando está váriavel?

Comment: Como está o `header.php`?

Comment: Está linkado no tópico @JonathandeToni e Francisco

Comment: Coloque as partes relevantes dos códigos aqui na pergunta, para que todos possam ter acesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você deve ter confundido a variável de conexão.

Você está usando assim na linha 17 e 18 do seu header.php:

```
$conectar=new DB;
$conectar=$conectar->conectar();
```

E assim na linha do erro:

```
$validaremail=mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'");
```

Tenta trocar a variável **$conexao** para **$conectar**, conforme você iniciou ali.

deveria ficar assim:

```
$validaremail=mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'");
```

A sua função da classe DB **conectar()** que retorna `return $conexao;`, mas o que vale é a variável que chama essa função no código:

```
$conectar=$conectar->conectar();
```

Se mesmo corrigindo esse erro, aparecer novos erros, você edita essa pergunta colocando no final os novos erros que surgirem.

**EDITADO**

Erro na classe **Cadastro** do arquivo **Cadastro.class.php**:

Classes e funções não conseguem acessar varáveis externas. Portanto a linha 15 (`$insert=mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT...`) da sua classe não consegue acessar a variável `$conexao`, e mesmo que você mudar para `$conectar` também não irá funcionar.

Você precisa inserir a variável para dentro da classe, e sugiro o método mágico `__construct()` mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

   class Cadastro{
        private $conexao;

        public function __construct($varconexao) {
          $this->conexao = $varconexao;
        }

         public function cadastrar($nome, $nickt, $nickp, $email, $face, $senha, $tel1, $tel2){
 ...
   $insert=mysqli_query($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO usuario...
 ...
         }
    }
 ?>
```

Ou seja, você cria uma variável `$conexao` para sua classe, e ao iniciar a classe você atribui a sua variável externa para dentro da sua classe utilizando: `new Cadastro($sua_variavel_de_conexao);`.

Então agora é só corrigir o seu **header.php** na linha que você chama a função:

```
     $cadastro = new Cadastro($conectar);
     echo "<div class='flash'>";
     $cadastro->cadastrar($nome, $nickt, $nickp, $email, $face, $senha, $tel1, $tel2);
     echo "</div>";
```

Você já utiliza a variável **$conectar** para sua classe de conexão, recomendo utilizar outra variável para o cadastro, conforme fiz acima com **$cadastro**. Se você utilizar a mesma variável como está fazendo atualmente `$conectar=new Cadastro;` ou `$conectar=$conectar->cadastrar`, você acaba sobrescrevendo ela, e futuramente poderá te dar mais dor de cabeça, dependendo de como for criando seu código.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver 2 erros, porém ficaram mais dois. Expliquei no tópico.

Comment: editei a resposta colocando a solução pros 2 erros que está ocorrendo. Da uma olhadinha se resolve, e se der certo não esquece depois de marcar a resposta como correta para ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema que você no futuro. ^^

Comment: Acho que fiz algo errado. Agora ele dá os seguintes erros: https://hastebin.com/ovajizupol.tex Esse erro não entendi, pois como poder ver acima, eu fiz o include do Cadastro.class. Atualmente o header está assim: https://hastebin.com/howosifugo.xml e o Cadastro.class: https://hastebin.com/vobijepewe.xml

Comment: Quando vc inicia uma classe vc atribui a classe para uma variável, no seu caso vc fez `$cadastro=new Cadastro($conectar);`, Entao a partir dai a variável cadastro terá as mesmas funções da sua classe. Então quando vc vai chamar a função vc deverá fazer assim: `$variaveldaclasse->funcao()`. O seu erro é q onde vc deveria chamar a função vc colocou um **$** chamando outra variavel inexistente `$cadastro->$cadastrar($nome, $ni...`. Deste modo está errado. você deve chamar assim: `$cadastro->cadastrar($nome, $ni...`.